# How to create a swift notebook on google colab

Tags: swift, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, swift-for-tensorflow

I have seen some nice demo on the dev summit on Swift for Tensorflow. So would like to try this out.

I could open this notebook:

https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/docs/site/tutorials/custom_differentiation.ipynb

and if you view the nb runtime setting, the runtime type dropdown indicated "**Swift**".

[image]

However, I can't find anywhere in the colab menu how you can create a notebook thats swift from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presently, the simplest way is to create a copy of an existing swift notebook. Use the menu item File -> Save a copy in Drive...

Comment: Thanks. So this is a bit experimental I assume. Looking forward to see this option in its rightful place soon,

Comment: I also suspect there may be a simple hack on the notebook?? How would colab know a notebook is to be swift or python?

Comment: The kernel type is specified in the notebook JSON. Existing swift notebooks have a kernelspec in their JSON configured by hand rather than via the Colab UI.

Answer (score 3):

For those who want to do hack, or just upload a blank notebook thats configured to run Swift once it gets to Colab, here's maybe useful json snippets:

```
{"nbformat":4,"nbformat_minor":0,"metadata":{"colab":{"name":"Blank for Swift.ipynb","version":"0.3.2","provenance":[{"file_id":"https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/docs/site/tutorials/custom_differentiation.ipynb","timestamp":1552503857805}],"collapsed_sections":[]},"kernelspec":{"name":"swift","display_name":"Swift"},"accelerator":"GPU"},"cells":[{"metadata":{"id":"iROrFnecc1gX","colab_type":"code","colab":{}},"cell_type":"code","source":[""],"execution_count":0,"outputs":[]}]}
```